# Operations must use an updatable query

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I combined information from multiple excel sheets using union query. Afterwards, I tried updating the field of another table using this union query.
While everything seems to be fine, I am getting the following error:

> "Operations must use an updatable query".

Can you please help me solve this problem?

My code:

```
UPDATE Audits 
INNER JOIN [Combined excel] ON Audits.VIN = [Combined excel].VIN
SET Audits.Transit_Report = [Combined excel].[Arrival date];
```

Comment: Is this really a mysql query?

Comment: I think this is Access. Check permissions on your Audits-file.

Comment: @Solarflare I think the square brackets mean it's SQL-Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event that you are really trying to do this in SQL Server (as the syntax sort-of suggests):

```
UPDATE a
     SET Transit_Report = c.[Arrival date]
FROM Audits a INNER JOIN
     [Combined excel] c
     ON a.VIN = c.VIN;
```